# Is it an array inside another array or are we looking for a certain value in the array?

Tags: python

i know this might be a bit beginner level type of code but i am getting a bit confused by this code below. i don't know what is happening. may someone be kind enough to explain it to me? And what is the output of the code?

```
lest = [3, 1, -2]         

print(lest[lest[-1]])


3

1

-1

-2
```

What really is happening here, especially with `lst[lst[-1]]`? i do not understand the concept being shown here. are we looking for a value in a multi-dimensional array or what?

Comment: Your code does not produce this output. Please double check your example.

Comment: To be precise, after renaming `lest` to `lst` the output of your code fragment is `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lest = [3, 1, -2]

print(lest[lest[-1]])
```

Okay easier if you break it up.

First:

`lest[-1]` will give us the last value of list `lest` which is `-2`

Second:

```
lest[lest[-1]]
```

Since we know `lest[-1] = -2` we know that this is equivalent to:

```
lest[-2]
```

Now your code is going to return the second to last digit of `lest` which is `1`

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3.7 helpin.py 
> 1
> ```